# Remove or truncate site rss in <content:encoded>

Tags: rss, feed

By default, all post's content is included into rss (content:encoded element).
I would like to convert reader to visit website.

Currently, `description` element is truncated, but `content:encoded` contains full post. Eg:

```
    <description><![CDATA[<a href="https://wolnyfinansowo.pl/robocash-recenzja-2022/" title="Robocash Recenzja (2022)" rel="nofollow"><img width="150" height="150" src="https://wolnyfinansowo.pl/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Pasted-1-150x150.png" class="webfeedsFeaturedVisual wp-post-image" alt="Robocash recenzja" style="display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; clear:both;max-width: 100%;" link_thumbnail="1" /></a><p>Po przeszło roku inwest...</p><p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="https://wolnyfinansowo.pl/robocash-recenzja-2022/">Robocash Recenzja (2022): 12,74% zysku</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="https://wolnyfinansowo.pl">Wolny Finansowo</a>.</p>]]></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[<a ... {full post's content}</content:encoded>
```

How to trim or even remove content:encoded element?

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this by adding a code snippet to truncate get_the_content_feed via filter:

```
function truncateFeedContent( $content )
{
    $content = get_the_excerpt();

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'truncateFeedContent' );
```

By default, `get_the_content_feed` [show all content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content_feed/)